# Angular ng-change for select not calling the declared method

Tags: javascript, html, select, angularjs

I have the following html form select statement

```
<select ng-change="setBillGroup()" ng-model="bill.groupId" class="span8" ng-options="d.id as d.name for d in groups"></select>
```

and the js

```
myApp.controller('myAppController', function($scope, myAppService) {

.....
function setBillGroup(){
 console.log("setBillGroup method called!");
    ......
 }

....
});
```

But for some reason the setBillGroup() never seems to get called when I select something or the other in the form.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to define the method in the scope.

```
$scope.setBillGroup = function(){
 console.log("setBillGroup method called!");
    ......
 };
```

Comment: Wow! Never felt this dumb! Thank you!

Comment: Oh my god - just passed by, searching for a related problem - and the only thing I never checked, was wether the called function was in scope. THANK YOU SO MUCH