# Angularjs 1.4 on-change not firing with Select

Tags: angularjs

Please find the [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ocg6t9XCipw7xXv5nJfs?p=info)

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
       $scope.levels = [{LevelId:0,LevelName: "Level 1"}, {LevelId:1,LevelName: "Level 2" }];
        $scope.updateLevel = function() {
            console.log("Fired on change");
            $scope.result="Data Changed";
        }
    });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label for="textbox3">Select Level</label>
  <select id="LevelSelect" class="form-control" ng-Change="updateLevel()" ng-model="selectedLevel" ng-options="lvl as level.LevelName for level in levels"></select>
  <p>{{result}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I referred to the various SO questions like [on not calling the declared method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005120/angular-ng-change-for-select-not-calling-the-declared-method) and [onchange not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370555/ng-change-not-working-on-ng-select). Advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use `ng-options` is incorrect there for the rendered options values is getting `undefined:undefined` for all the options check below image, and when you change the selected item its not trigger `ng-change` event because all the values are same.

[image]

so change it to,

```
ng-options="level as level.LevelName for level in levels"
```

please refer this angular [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

[UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/21j5WN3q95C95tlOONCt?p=preview)

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks a lot Toress. It did made a difference after lot of struggle. :)

Comment: yea glad to help you :) and please go though the angular doc which i add, and use `ng-change` simple `c`, that will not cause any prob but its the standard. :) cheerz